# Compile PHP with static libpng

Tags: php

I'm trying to compile PHP 7.0.30 from sources with statically linked libpng.

```
ldd ./php
```

returns:

```
libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f76b990b000)
```

For a php compiled this way:

```
./configure --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes --with-png-dir=/usr/lib/
make
```

I thought the final php binary would embed **libpng.a** static library but apparently it still craves for **libpng16.so.16** dynamic library on its execution.

Is there a way to compile a really static PHP?

Comment: Could you try with `--prefix=/usr --with-libdir=lib` instead of `--with-png-dir=/usr/lib/`?

Comment: Siad, thank you for you suggestion. I've just tried it but it gives `/usr/bin/ld: ext/standard/.libs/image.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`. I'll dig further into this.

Comment: `DSO missing ...` could maybe be solved with the help of https://askubuntu.com/questions/870620/undefined-reference-to-symbol-uncompress-dso-missing-from-command-line